# How to run paypal's cURL example on windows 7 32 bit?

Tags: curl, paypal

i am working with paypal integration in android application. My question is, how to make a call to the paypal's example access token request to view the response.That means can i call that cURL request via Browser like normal api request? If no means,How can i get the response like below?

Example access token request:

```
curl -v https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token \
  -H "Accept: application/json" \
  -H "Accept-Language: en_US" \
  -u "EOJ2S-Z6OoN_le_KS1d75wsZ6y0SFdVsY9183IvxFyZp:EClusMEUk8e9ihI7ZdVLF5cZ6y0SFdVsY9183IvxFyZp" \
  -d "grant_type=client_credentials"
```

Sample response:

```
{
  "scope": "https://api.paypal.com/v1/payments/.* https://api.paypal.com/v1/vault/credit-card https://api.paypal.com/v1/vault/credit-card/.*",
  "access_token": "{accessToken}",
  "token_type": "Bearer",
  "app_id": "APP-6XR95014SS315863X",
  "expires_in": 28800
}
```

Comment: You can do that with Postman chrome extension or GitBash command line. See my answer for further detail

Comment: Ya.. it works.. thank u.!! Then how did u convert the -u (EOJ2S-Z6OoN_le_KS1d75wsZ6y0SFdVsY9183IvxFyZp:EClusMEUk8e9ihI7ZdVLF5cZ6y0SFdVsY9183IvxFyZp) to Basic base64_encode ? how can i convert it myself.?

Comment: First convert username:password in here http://www.opinionatedgeek.com/dotnet/tools/base64encode/ and then let say result is `result`, then you will append `Basic ` at the start of `result`. Finally it will be `Basic result`

Comment: An upvote to my answer will be appreciated then :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do that with [Postman Client](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman-rest-client/fdmmgilgnpjigdojojpjoooidkmcomcm?hl=en) chrome extension. Install extension and provide details like below;

[image]

And click **send** button. Important point here;

`-H` will be sent in header fields,

`-u` needs to be convert like below and send s in header;

`Authorization: Basic base64_encode(username:password)` in your case it will be;

`Basic RU9KMlMtWjZPb05fbGVfS1MxZDc1d3NaNnkwU0ZkVnNZOTE4M0l2eEZ5WnA6RUNsdXNNRVVrOGU5aWhJN1pkVkxGNWNaNnkwU0ZkVnNZOTE4M0l2eEZ5WnA=`

`-d` will be sent as url-form-encoded form.

Alternatively you can perform this action by using Git Bash. Install Git Bash from [here](http://git-scm.com/download/win)

And open git bash terminal, and copy/paste your curl query like below;

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`curl` and `tar` were added natively to [Windows 10 Insider build 17063](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/tar-and-curl-come-to-windows/). For older version of windows it's still possible to install [curl](https://curl.haxx.se/windows/) on Windows manually.